# positioning and moving a shape in console application(console.write("bla bla bla");)

Tags: c#, console-application, shapes

my console application in like below :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Now = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    if (Now == "2011/08/12")
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Money..........");
        Console.Read();
    }
    else
    {
        int n = 6;

        var result = string.Join("\r\n", from i in Enumerable.Range(1, n)
                                         where i != 2
                                         let stars = Enumerable.Repeat('*', i)
                                         let indent = new string(' ', n - i)
                                         select indent + string.Join(" ", stars));

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**the upper codes are in c#**

my questions :
1- how can we find some shape examples in console application like the upper example with *!
the upper example with stars is too simple / i am looking for some better shapes like hanging somebody (just for fun)
2- how can i move console.write window with code ?
3- how can i move shape inside console.write window ?
4- how can i set consol.write window positioning ?

thanks in advance

Comment: @Shamim Hafiz sorry / i edit my Q

Comment: I am sorry, i dont understand what your code does nor what you wish to do. Either give the full code, so can compile and do some fix.

Comment: @zenwalker : hi / the upper codes in Q are ok and u can test them in a console application / besides my Q's have nothing to do with these codes! plz let me to know that is there any wrong with my Q's!

Comment: I did run your code which you have pased in Q, its not compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx

1 - You will have to work out the shapes yourself, enjoy.

Here is a code that does somthing but you already have some in your example.

```
int pos = 0
int limit = 80
while (true)
{
    StringBuilder line  = new StringBuilder(limit);
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        if (i = pos)
        {
            line.Append("A");
        }
        else
        {
            line.Append(" ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
    if (pos = (limit - 1))
    {
        pos = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        pos++;
    }
}
```

2 - You can move the console window with `Console.WindowLeft` and `Console.WindowsTop`

3 - Shape is the wrong word and idea here, you can only read and write lines of text. You could create the impression of a moving shape by using a char say `0` or  as background, populating the whole line as "blank", Then use some other chars to represent your shape. See the example above.

4 - Same as 2.

Comment: really thanks for answer / but is there a way for moving console window around the screen ?

Comment: Does changing Console.WindowLeft and Console.WindowsTop not work?

Comment: @Jodrell: that is intended to scroll the content (relative to the scrollbuffer)

Answer (score 1):

To relocate the actual console window, you'd need to do `SetWindowPos` with `GetConsoleWindow` (Win32 API) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548838/setting-position-of-a-console-window-opened-in-a-winforms-app/1548881#1548881).

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

//    
SetWindowPos(GetConsoleWindow(), 0, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
```

On manipulating shapes *inside* the console window, have a look at [MonoCurses](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses). I'm not sure whether it works on Windows yet, but is quite advanced (having Window, Dialog, Application abstractions and a lot of widgets for data entry)