# Setting C# console application location to a secondary screen

Tags: c#, console-application, multiscreen

**Overview:** I am working on a project which involves a WCF and multiple types of clients. I have created several Test clients and I have a WCF which is hosted in a console app.
This results in me having multiple application windows (I currently have 4) when debugging and every time I run them I have to arrange them on multiple screens (I have 2).

**Question:** I wonder is there a way to set a position of Console application to the secondary screen without a need to drag it all the time.

Comment: You can use Console.SetWindowPosition() to move the console window.  Use the System.Windows.Forms.Screen class to find out where your second monitor is located so you can pass the proper arguments to SetWindowPosition().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the console to the wanted screen. Go to properties. Note the location. Use that.

Comment: You mean to untick "Let system position window" property? If so then it works.

Comment: Yeah, but you can still see the numbers grayed out IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you'll find that the answer given on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1548881/308012) will cover you.

It'll mean saving the position of the console window when it closes and also checking that the position is within the displayable area of the desktop on startup, but it demonstrates how to position the console window for both console applications and windows forms ones.

Comment: That is also useful, and it's a bit cleaner solution. But as I need this only for debugging, setting properties of console is enough for me.