# Create a Console Application in a windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, console

I have a Windows forms application that I wont a console extension.
I cant find a way to add a new console and also if there is a way how would i call it?

Comment: Do you want output like Console Application or you want to execute the console application?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, i wont to have a separate class controlling the Console Application.

Comment: I do not understand what you 'wont' to do. Give us an example.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472282/show-console-in-windows-application

Comment: Ok, I have a windows form application and i wont a Console application to pop up. that's all.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15079092/366904). Also related: [How do I add a console like element to a c# winforms program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/252323), [how to run a winform from console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/277771)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pop up a Console application it is as simple as:

```
Process cmdProcess = new Process();
cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
cmdProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Console class needs to be in my project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an Executable (output of a console application) from WinForms, then as @JeffRSon quoted

```
Process cmdProcess = new Process();
cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "YourExecutablePath.exe";
cmdProcess.Start();
```

If you want an application to be run in Command Prompt then the code as:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.WorkingDirectory = "Path of the Executable";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);

string sCommandLine = string.Format("YourExecutable.exe -{1}", YourParameterValues);

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(sCommandLine);
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Close();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry but i need the console class to be in my project.